# Move the origin point to the cursor in Edit Mode

Tags: 3d-cursor, origin

I have a model where I would like to rotate an area of the object, in this case a mouth of a ordinary beast along a defined point, marked here with the 3D Cursor. And I am trying to move the selected areas Origin Point to the cursor, so in edit mode i press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+C and select "Origin to 3D Cursor. But then I get an error message that says, "Operation cannot be preformed in edit mode". Why??

I have Heard that you can snap the 3D Cursor to an object/vertex/edge/face but I have not found any reference of it...
It is a mirrored object btw.[image: Trying to move Origin Point]
[image]

Comment: My guess Ulf (and welcome to bse) is you are confusing an [objects origin point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/origin.html#object-origin) with [Pivot point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html)  Set pivot point type to 3d cursor.

Answer (score 3):

What I understood  about your issue, you want to open mouth and close it.

Please try following steps:

1. Select the base edges as shown in the image below, snap the 3D cursor to this edge, by hitting **Shift + S** and selecting **Cursor to selected**
   [image]
2. Change the **Pivot Point** to 3D Cursor
   [image]
3. Select the full mouth and rotate it as required.
   [image]

You may also create a **Shape key** for easy rotate and animate

When you are done with it you may change back the **Pivot point** to **Median point**

Best of luck!